# excel: time sequence is not unified

Tags: excel, time, format

[image]

dear 
as you can see in uploaded picture it is an excel sheet downloaded from data logger to record in wind speed every hour the problem that time sequence not change ()
in row 87 to 108 it is data from 12/November/2014 2:00 Am to 12/November/2014 11:pm the row 109 suppose to be 13/November/2014 12:00 AM (13/11/2014 12:00 AM )but it is change to 11/13/2014 12:00 AM 
so any have solution to this matter

Comment: You should import the data properly. This kind of problem is better addressed at the point of import than after. Do you copy/paste the data or use Import Data?

Comment: As you see in the date example `3/14/12 1:30 PM` in your screenshot, the date is `MDY` `MM/DD/YY`. So your `12/11/14` is **not** "12/November/2014" but December 11 2014. So, as @Jerry stated already, something was going wrong while your data import.

Comment: no the data is downloaded not  imported

Comment: Then the download source is wrong already. As said, according to your screenshot, the `12/11/14` is December 11 2014 and the `11/13/14` is November 13 2014.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"no the data is downloaded not imported" <--- what they mean is.. when you have the original downloaded data.. don't format it as "Date". Leave it as is it.. ("General"). Then use 5 extra columns to check the date and time.. put in these formulas and drag it downwards.

```
column 1 --> =month(A87)
column 2 --> =day(A87)
column 3 --> =year(A87)
column 4 --> =hour(A87)
column 5 --> =minute(A87)
```

From the pattern , you should see a pattern if the month/day was formatted wrongly. If it is.. just use one more extra column to combine the "correct" date & time by using `=date(...)+time(...)` .
 Have a try and share if these works or not. We can proceed from there.

Hope this helps. ( :