# Excel Date Issue - Save Adobe PDF to XML 2003

Tags: excel, xml, date

All:

I'm using Excel 2013 and Adobe Acrobat XI.

I have a 3,000 page PDF (text searchable) that I saved to XML spreadsheet 2003 (NOTE:  I tried OCR tools like Monarch, but it didn't work.  This is one of those situations where the user centered text in a cell, but the adjacent cells were not centered and as a result Monarch splits the records up and long story short:  It's a mess.  Saving the PDF as XML exported as clean as i can get).

The issue I have are the dates:  This is an example of how the date looks in the PDF:

[image]

However, when I export the PDF to Excel, and then open it, the date APPEARS to be the same format but look closely (upper left highlight) - Excel has decided to transpose the format from 4/6/2016 to 6/4/2016:

[image]

EDIT:  I've done a work-around in that I can copy the dates to Notepad, then copy them back to the spreadsheet.  But I'm curious as to why this is.

Thank you.

Comment: How does the `XML` look like? Should be `<Cell><Data ss:Type="DateTime">2016-04-06T00:00:00.000</Data></Cell>` for date cells. If so there cannot be any confusion about `MDY` vs. `DMY`.

Comment: @Axel:  Thanks for the reply.  If I look at the format properties for a date in the XML, the format is 14/3/2012 (custom - Chinese (Hong Kong SAR)).  Not sure what that means.  But the issue I have is that Excel has already determined how it will format this cell, before I even open the file.

Comment: You told, you are "saving the PDF as XML". So my question was: How does the `XML` look like? Do opening the `XML` using a text editor (or maybe a XML editor) and have a look into it. Date cells should look like `<Cell><Data ss:Type="DateTime">2016-04-06T00:00:00.000</Data></Cell>`. If they look different, then you will always have problems with `MDY` vs. `DMY` date locales. Then your "saving the PDF as XML" is incorrect.

Comment: Opened the XML in sublime text editor and I see this:  

ss:Type="DateTime" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">2016-06-04</ss:Data></Cell><Cell

Comment: It's in the wrong format...looks like I need another solution.

Comment: Maybe the piece of software you are using for "saving the PDF as XML" has a setting for whether `MDY` or `DMY` shall be used for dates? You have not told us what exactly you are using for "saving the PDF as XML".

Comment: I mentioned above that I'm using "Adobe Acrobat XI".  Not sure where I would change the properties/preferences.  Maybe I need to upgrade.

Comment: Well, I never used this pricely software product. But seems [only settings for decimal and thousands separators are possible](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/file-format-options-pdf-export.html#spreadsheet_options). So sad that `Adobe` seems not to know the difference between `DMY` and `MDY` date locales. But also sad that those differences always nor present in 21th century. `YYYY-MM-DD` **is** the one and only correct date format. Nobody will write 123 as 321 and expect someone will read this as 3 + 20 + 100.

Comment: try this : Copy the date column > paste in new file. | Add 5 columns like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47386749/excel-time-sequence-is-not-unified/51743636#51743636) and check if it is the month/day you need. If yes.. then no editing needed. If no, you may use `=date(col1,col2,col3)` to 'generate the date/format you need.. then paste it back to your xml file. ( :